# mysql db result convert as a json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to write a auto complete, which the auto complete items load one time when the PHP page loads. With the items that are fetched from mysql DB , i have create a json array like this

```
<?php
$bnkArray = array();
$sql_bnk = mysql_query("SELECT BName, BCode, ID  FROM bank");
while($rBnk = mysql_fetch_array($sql_bnk)){

    $bnkDet = array(
        'label' => $rBnk['BName'],
        'value' => $rBnk['BName'],
        'otherDetails' => $rBnk['BName'].'||'. $rBnk['BCode'].'||'. $rBnk['ID'] 
    );  
    array_push($bnkArray, $bnkDet);
}

?>
```

i need this array as like this javascript array

```
<script>

var bankSource11 = [
      {
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        otherDetails: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",

      },
      {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        otherDetails: "the official user interface library for jQuery",

      },
      {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        otherDetails: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",

      }
    ];
</script>
```

if i call this array like this in my auto complete this is not working

```
var bankSource = [<?php echo  $bnkArray; ?>];
```

what is this array type.. 
how to do this.

this is the autocomplete part

```
$(this).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: bankSource,
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).val( ui.item.label );
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                console.log(ui.item.value +' ____ ' + ui.item.otherDetails);
                $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
                $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
                $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.otherDetails );

                return false;
              }
            })


        }
```

Comment: Are you using javascript and PHP on same page?

Comment: yes both are in one page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please replace

```
var bankSource = [<?php echo  $bnkArray; ?>];
```

with

```
var bankSource = <?php echo json_encode($bnkArray); ?>;
```

Comment: after changing the **var bankSource = <?php echo json_encode($bnkArray); ?>;**  the auto complete is showing empty results

Comment: Does the generated javascript array looks okay? Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: there is not any errors in the console, i am confusing with the array

Comment: please check the my auto complete  code to i have update the codes

Comment: the array now look like this var bankSource = [[{"label":"Public Bank Berhad","value":"Public Bank Berhad","otherDetails":"Public Bank Berhad||7296||48"},{"label":"Pan Asia Bank","value":"Pan Asia Bank","otherDetails":"Pan Asia Bank||7311||50"},{"label":"National Mercantile Bank","value":"National Mercantile Bank","otherDetails":"National Mercantile Bank||7454||51"},]];

Comment: Why are there double "[" and "]"s? Please remove the braces around `<?php echo json_encode($bnkArray); ?>`.

Comment: I think that you also need to implement `_renderItem` function because you are using objects in your source array. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176552/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-objects

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample example which i modified accroding to your requirement. 
Kindly study it and let me know if you have any question.

```
 <?php
    $bnkArray = array();
    $sql_bnk = mysql_query("SELECT BName, BCode, ID  FROM bank");
    while($rBnk = mysql_fetch_array($sql_bnk)){

        $bnkDet = array(
            'label' => $rBnk['BName'],
            'value' => $rBnk['BName'],
            'otherDetails' => $rBnk['BName'].'||'. $rBnk['BCode'].'||'. $rBnk['ID'] 
        );  
        array_push($bnkArray, $bnkDet);
    }

    ?>


    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script>
      $(function() {
        var bankSource11  = <?php echo json_encode($bnkArray); ?>;
        $( "#My_Input" ).autocomplete({
          source: bankSource11  
        });
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="ui-widget">
      <input id="My_Input">
    </div>
```

Comment: if the **[ ]** remove in the bankSource11  variable it is working.. thank you for your effort

Comment: @NSK If you find this answer helpful Mark it as accepted and upvote. So, other can also get confidence.

Answer (score 1):

change this line like this,

```
var bankSource = [<?php echo  $bnkArray; ?>];
```

to

```
var bankSource = "<?php echo  json_encode($bnkArray); ?>";
```

Php variable is enclosed with quotes and assigned to js variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should do following :

```
var bankSource11 = [<?php echo json_encode($bnkArray); ?>];
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the single quotes, because it's string:

```
var bankSource = '<?php echo json_encode($bnkArray); ?>';
```