# jQuery UI autocomplete object not returning anything

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui

I am having problems trying to get an autocomplete field populating with AJAX. One account <kbd>user</kbd> can have multiple <kbd>members</kbd> associated to it.

I have taken a step back by manually defining the array to get it working but something is still wrong. I assume it's something in my jQuery UI script as it's a big question mark for me at the moment.

The functionality I'm trying to create is that the user can start entering the name of a member (eg `Smith, John`) and selects it, the page will [impersonate the user](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html) and reload the same page but appending the path with (in the example of `Smith, John` it would return `?_switch_user=jsmith`)

HTML code:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="search" id="search-names" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter member name">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

jQuery UI script:

```
var UserArray = [
  { "label": "Smith, John", "value": "jsmith" },
  { "label": "Doe, Jane", "value": "jdoe1990" }
];

$( "#search-names" ).autocomplete({
  source: UserArray,
  minLength: 2,
  change: function() {
    var UserArray = $(this).val();
    if (!UserArray) return;

    window.location = window.location + '?_switch_user=' + UserArray.value
  }
});
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, autocomplete only takes an array of strings, not objects? I could be wrong on this. EDIT: I was wrong indeed. It does take objects. Didn't know that :)

Comment: Two things you have to change. 1) change your variabele name in your `change()` since it's the same as your array. 2) "label" and "value" should not be with quotes, but without them. see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/wxh77sue/

Comment: Thanks very much @Jorrex - I thought the variable in `change()` was assigning the previous `UserArray`...(!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$("#search-names").autocomplete({
    source: UserArray,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, matched) {
        console.log(matched)
        window.location = window.location + '?_switch_user=' + matched.item.value
    }
  });
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5fn9fsqk/1/)

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks @Theodore :) .....now I just need to figure out how to get Symfony to wrap the data from my database into the structure of `[
  { "label": "Smith, John", "value": "jsmith" },
  { "label": "Doe, Jane", "value": "jdoe1990" }
];`...!

Comment: If your data has different structure you can use a decorator to match autocomplete's desired input structure. Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176552/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-objects

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple what is wrong with your code.

1) You're using `UserArray`for your array of objects, but in the `change()` function, you declare another variable with the same name. This should be different from each other.

2) the property names in your objects shouldn't be enclosed with "".

See the code below or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/wxh77sue/)

**HTML**

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="search" id="search-names" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter member"/>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
  Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
var userArray = [
  {
    label: "Smith, John",
    value: "jsmith"
  },
  {
    label: "Doe, Jane",
    value: "jdoe1990"
  }
];

$("#search-names").autocomplete({
    source: userArray,
  minLength: 2,
  change: function() {
    var user = $(this).val();
    if(!user) return;

    window.location = window.location + "?_switch_user=" + user;
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Jorrex - I tried that too and works well too thanks. I suppose label/value not wrapped in quotes is better practice? In case it's of help for others - this approach populates the text field with `value` strings whereas the other given answer populates the text field with ``label` strings