# .autocomplete() data with remote json

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I have some troubles whith .autocomplete function.
What i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( ".search" ).autocomplete({
      source: [{label:'link label1', searchLink:'http://link1.com'},
               {label:'link label2', searchLink:'http://link2.com'},
               {label:'link label3', searchLink:'http://link3.com'}],
      select:function(e,ui) { 
      location.href = ui.item.searchLink;
}
});
</script>
```

And i need put this json content to direct file and read data from it with this aoutocomplete data:

```
{
{label:'link label1', searchLink:'http://link1.com'},
{label:'link label2', searchLink:'http://link2.com'},
{label:'link label3', searchLink:'http://link3.com'}
}
```

Can somebody help me with it?) Maybe some way with $.getJSON() will be wery great solution:)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ did you check the link?

Comment: Yes)) And try to do, but i can't:(

Comment: did you add json content to your json file?

Comment: i cant add data to .autocomplete sourse right way. My json file content is: {{label:'link label1', searchLink:'http://link1.com'},{label:'link label2', searchLink:'http://link2.com'},{label:'link label3', searchLink:'http://link3.com'}} and i need some .autocomplete({source:$.getJSON('json.json')........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically below is what you need to do.

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                delay: 500,
                minLength: 3,
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.getJSON("JSON file name", {                       
                        q: request.term,
                        page_limit: 10
                    }, function(data) {
                        // data is an array of objects and must be transformed for autocomplete to use
                        var array = $.map(data, function(m) {
                            return {
                                label: m.lable,
                                searchLink: m.searchLink
                            };
                        });
                        response(array);
                    });
                }
            });
```

Below post explains how to use remote JSON with auto complete.

http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2013/12/jquery-ui-autocomplete-examples.html#example-3

It has complete code as well

Comment: can u show json file souse example for this code? with my json file it didtn work:(

Comment: Can you add the code in jsFiddle.net and provide the link

Comment: in JSON link, change to "https" and validate the JSON in https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and then try JSFiddle

Comment: Also include https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.min.js in the external resources

Comment: what does it mean "for autocomplete to use"? does autocomplete only work with label and searchLink properties?

Comment: It looks like it needs to be label & value

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a callback to work with the data;

```
$.getJSON('getSource.url',function(data){
       /* Work with your data here */
})
```

you may find [jQuery UI autocomplete with objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176552/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-objects) useful