# How can I pass a JSON array to jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this Json data that i would want to pass to JQuery.ui autocomplete

```
   <input type="text" id="symptom_checker" name="search_symptom" />
```

JSON encoded data

```
 var symptoms = [{"symptom_name":"Overall sensation of feeling unwell"},{"symptom_name":"cough"},{"symptom_name":"cough with blood mucus"}];
```

if i pass it to this function

```
    $("#symptom_checker").autocomplete({
       source: symptoms
     });
```

when enter the symptom name it doesn't work, but if i try to use this json data

```
   var symptoms = ["Overall sensation of feeling unwell", "cough", "cough with blood mucus"];
```

JQUERY

```
      $("#symptom_checker").autocomplete({
       source: symptoms
     });
```

It works fine.
How do I solve this ?

Comment: Documentation of autocomplete say it should not be a multidimensional array. You should map your json to not multidimensional but you can search in google by 'jquery autocomplete multidimensional array'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI autocomplete with objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176552/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-objects)

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation it supports two array formats.

1. Array of Strings
2. Array of objects with attributes label and value ex: `[{label:'' , value:''}]`. You can also have only `value` as attribute.

You have to convert your array into any of these format.