# Display two different values in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I'm trying to set an autocomplete that would display 2 values in the dropdown list. Precisely, i have a users database with names and ID, and i want search an user by typing his name, and then have the choice between all users that have this name.
Example : i have two users called Jack, with ID 1 and 2 
I want to be able to select which Jack i want by seing the IDs in the dropdown list

Here's my actual code : 
HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <form>
        Nom: <input type="text" id="ag_nom_pub" value="Oih">                <!-- this is the field used for the autocomplete -->
    </form>
</div>`
```

JS :

```
    $('#ag_nom_pub').autocomplete({
    // This shows the min length of charcters that must be typed before the autocomplete looks for a match.
    minLength: 3,source: function (request, response) {
       response($.map(ag_pandaone_webservice('ag_publicitaire_get_list',$('#ag_nom_pub').val(), function (value, key) {
            return {
                label: value.NOMPUBLICITAIRE,
                value: value.ENTITYID
            }
        })));    
},    
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $('#ag_nom_pub').val(ui.item.NOMPUBLICITAIRE);
        return false;
    },
    // Once a value in the drop down list is selected, do the following:
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // place the person.given_name value into the textfield called 'select_origin'...
        $('#ag_nom_pub').val(ui.item.NOMPUBLICITAIRE);
        // and place the person.id into the hidden textfield called 'link_origin_id'. 
        $('#idPub').val(ui.item.ENTITYID);
            return false;
    }
});
```

The NOMPUBLICITAIRE and ENTITYID are the name of the variables from the users database i want to display in my list.
The `$.map(ag_pandaone_webservice('ag_publicitaire_get_list',$('#ag_nom_pub').val()`
return an array of object which contains the ID and the name of the user

The actual code i have was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176552/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-objects)

At the moment i'm getting this error when i type 3 letters in my input field :

[image]

I've been looking on the internet for this error but i don't really understand what causes it and i don't know what can i do to fix it.

If anyone could help me in any way i'd be grateful :)
Don't hesitate to tell me if you need more information from my code or attempts to fix the damn thing !

Thanks in advance and have a great day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to override the `_renderItem` function of autocomplete like this :

**For jQuery UI before 1.10 :**

```
$('#ag_nom_pub').autocomplete({
    // Your options goes there
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    // Here you are returning the element wich will be rendered

    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.ENTITYID + " - " + item.NOMPUBLICITAIRE + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

[**jsfiddle for versions before 1.10**](http://jsfiddle.net/LCv8L/977/)

**For jQuery UI after 1.10:**

```
$('#ag_nom_pub').autocomplete({
    // Your options goes there
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    // Here you are returning the element wich will be rendered

    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.ENTITYID + " - " + item.NOMPUBLICITAIRE + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

[**jsfiddle for versions after 1.10**](http://jsfiddle.net/LCv8L/978/)

---

> Before jquery UI 1.10, the data tag was `autocomplete` and since 1.10 it is `ui-autocomplete`. The same applies for `item.autocomplete` wich becomes `ui-autocomplete-item`
>
> Bonus link: [**jQuery UI 1.10 Upgrade Guide about autocomplete**](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#autocomplete)

Comment: Here is the link to a jsfiddle with the code i put in the original question : https://jsfiddle.net/0f2987mf/   (this is the first time i use jsfiddle so if i forgot something tell me :) )

Comment: @darzang Have your tried the `_renderItem` method ?

Comment: I replaced all the JS i orginally put in the question by what you told me, and now i got this error : ![Valid XHTML](http://hpics.li/7ebede8).

Comment: I updated my answer with a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCv8L/977/) which you can use for help

Comment: Your code works fine on jsfiddle, but i still have issues : my array is not defined nor declared in the js file, so my source is not a variable name but this :  `source: function (request, response) {
 response($.map(ag_pandaone_webservice('ag_publicitaire_get_list',$('#ag_nom_pub').val(), function (value, key) {
                return {
                    label: value.NOMPUBLICITAIRE,
                    value: value.ENTITYID
                }
            })));`         and i think my issue could come from this expression.

Comment: Yep, I forgot that, in the line `.append("<a>" + item.ENTITYID + " - " + item.NOMPUBLICITAIRE + "</a>")` you should just replace `ENTITYID` by `value` and `NOMPUBLICITAIRE` by `label`

Comment: When i try to run your code into my js for testing, i have this error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined"  I'm starting to think that the function i call in order to get the source somehow doesn't send me an array like i would like to. How could i change it so that it sends me an array ? ( or a json file would maybe more easier to use ? ) that's the first time i have to retrieve informations from a database and i don't know which type of answer could be more appropriate

Comment: What version of jQuery UI are you using ?

Comment: I'm using jquery jquery-ui-1.12.1

Comment: Works fine on jsfiddle and on my code ! The only thing left for me is to set my function to send me an array like the one you manually declare (named "tags"), i presume it's better that i create a new question right ? Anyway thank you for your time and answers :)