# jQuery UI Autocomplete: Load from Array of Objects: Filtering is broken

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm following the JSFiddle given [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28177271/1005607) as the solution to loading jQuery UI AutoComplete from a simple Array of Objects:

http://jsfiddle.net/khsbme4k/

The filtering is broken here. There are 2 data rows with a First_Name string, "Will" and "Willem", but if you type anything else e.g. "WA" you still get the full selection of 2 items, where there should be none.

```
  var data = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "Will",
            "last_name": "Smith",
            "created_at": "2015-01-27T13:09:20.243Z",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-27T13:09:20.243Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "first_name": "Willem",
            "last_name": "Dafoe",
            "created_at": "2015-01-27T13:17:23.479Z",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-27T13:17:23.479Z"
        }
    ];

$('#search').autocomplete({
        // This shows the min length of charcters that must be typed before the autocomplete looks for a match.
        minLength: 2,
source: function (request, response) {
           response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                return {
                    label: value.first_name,
                    value: value.id
                }
            }));

    },    
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $('#search').val(ui.item.first_name);
            return false;
        },
        // Once a value in the drop down list is selected, do the following:
        select: function(event, ui) {
            // place the person.given_name value into the textfield called 'select_origin'...
            $('#search').val(ui.item.first_name);
            // and place the person.id into the hidden textfield called 'link_origin_id'. 
            $('#link_origin_id').val(ui.item.id);
                return false;
        }
```

Comment: You need to pass the map data back to filtering. Use `$.ui.autocomplete.filter()` Example: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following code example of your `source`:

```
source: function(request, response) {
  var results;
  var aData = $.map(data, function(value, key) {
    return {
      label: value.first_name,
      value: value.id
    }
  });
  results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(aData, request.term);
  response(results);
}
```

First we map your data to `{ label, value }` pairs that Autocomplete is expecting. We then use `$.ui.autocomplete.filter()` to perform the expected filtering like Autocomplete does. This gives us our results array that we can send to `response()` to display.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/svnbw2uj/3/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use the indexOf() method to get the autocomplete list of search item.

```js
     $(function() {
    var data = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "Will",
            "last_name": "Smith",
            "created_at": "2015-01-27T13:09:20.243Z",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-27T13:09:20.243Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "first_name": "Willem",
            "last_name": "Dafoe",
            "created_at": "2015-01-27T13:17:23.479Z",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-27T13:17:23.479Z"
        }
    ];

var auto_array = {};
$('#search').autocomplete({
 // This shows the min length of charcters that must be typed before the autocomplete looks for a match.
 minLength: 2,
source: function (request, response) {
    response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
    
   //get the list of autocomplete start with search value. for case insensitive i used the toUpperCase() function.
   var first_name = value.first_name.toUpperCase()
   if(first_name.indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) != -1){
    label = value.first_name;
    auto_array[label] = value.id;
    return label;
   }else{
    return null;
   }
  }));

},    
 
  select: function(event, ui) {
  $('#link_origin_id').val(auto_array[ui.item.value]);
   }
     
});
});
```

```html
 
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <input type="text" id="search">
 <input type="text" id="link_origin_id">
```

Comment: @gene, try this code it will work. Before display the autocomplete list I used startsWith() function.

Comment: thanks a lot! only problems is "startsWith" which maybe should be "indexOf != -1"

Comment: yes, batter to use indexOf. I edit my code. Thanks!